# How can i generate soap4r wsdl2ruby classes in a namespace to avoid name collisions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap4r

I'm having a naming collision between my Address class used for db and the Address class generated using wsdl2ruby (and several other classes). I'm using soap4r.

Is there anyway to generate the soap4r classes in their own namespace so all the soap4r classes can see each other but not conflict with my application?

I'd rather not go with a dynamic generator (handsoap, savon) as this would greatly increase the volume of user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have namespaces, it has modules. From the source, it looks like the `--module_path [desiredModuleName]` option for `wsdl2ruby` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I refer to namespacing as a design pattern rather than a language specific syntax. I think this will work.